# in array for a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I tried to set an inArray with an object but it don't works

```
var test = {aa:1, bb:0}
console.log($.inArray(1,test))
```

I always have -1

thanks

Comment: That's because that's not an array. And it's not an object either.

Comment: Because `test` is not an array.  An array would look like `var test = [1, 0, ...]` - you cannot have associative arrays in javascript.

Comment: @cale_b you can have associative arrays in Javascript. They're called Objects

Comment: Yes but I post to have a solution to test if I have 1 in my array for exemple

Comment: @ant `{aa:1, bb:0}` is not an array. It's an object.

Comment: Your comment suggests that you're asking how to use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)? But with a *real* array, or with an object?

Comment: @cale_b you can even have non-numeric keys in an array, although they typically don't get iterated over.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - yes, you can have associative *objects*, but *objects* are not *arrays*, and therefore you can not have a true associative *array*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{} = object literal

[] = array object
```

`$.inArray` is designed to work with arrays. It will not work properly with objects as you have already figured out (it returns -1 no matter the circumstance). Speaking of objects, the syntax you used to create an object literal is ill-formed, it's not written as `{ a = b }` but rather as `{ a : b }`. Here is an example:

```
var test = { aa: 1, bb: 0 };
```

I also see that you're trying to find if a property of an object has a certain *value*, and not that the object has the property at all. If it were the latter case we'd use the `in` keyword or `.hasOwnProperty` function. But we'll need to make our own function for your case. Try this:

```
var inObject = function( obj, val ) {

    for ( var i in obj ) {

        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {

            if ( obj[i] === val ) return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

};
```

And we'll use it like this:

```
>>> var test = { aa: 1, bb: 0 };

>>> inObject( test, 1 );
    true
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you're doing something else. Actually you're trying to create an object, with object literal, which has properties `aa` and `bb`. The keys are `aa` and `bb` not `0`, `1`. You can try this:

```
var test = { aa:1, bb:0 };
console.log('aa' in test); //true
```

If you wish your key to be `0` and `1` you can try:

```
var test = { 1: 'aa', 0: 'bb' };
console.log(1 in test);  //true
```

And you can also:

```
var test = { 1: 'aa', 0: 'bb' };
console.log(test['1']);  //"aa"
```

If you want to check whether the object contains a value just:

```
function containsValue(obj, key) {
   for (var prop in obj) {
       if (obj[prop] === key) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
var test = { aa:1, bb:0 };
console.log(containsValue(test, 1)); //true
```

Comment: Yeah it isn't that's why I've edited it and in my answer it is: `{ aa:1, bb:0 };` :-)

Comment: yes but this is an ajax result I can't change it easily

Comment: So you're making an ajax request which is returning you `{aa=1, bb=0}`?

Comment: @ant are you trying to detect if an _object_ contains a specific _value_?

Comment: And you want to know whether `1` is a value to an object property or not?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I want to know if my objetc contain a value

Comment: @ant check out the last edition :-)